# Huawei Mobile Connect E170

Tags: hardware, sms, modem, gsm, gprs

I am trying to receive SMS messages with a Huawei Mobile Connect, Model: E170 device through hyper terminal but can't.

I used the below commands to initialize the modem:

AT+CMGF=1 
AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0  (But this gives me this error: +CMS ERROR: 303)

This same commands working on my nokia N70,  6630 and many other nokia models i can't remember.

I know the modem can receive and send SMS messages, but how do i do it?

Answer (score 2):

Below worked for me in Huawe E153.

```
at+cmgf=1 //Set text format
at+csmp=49,167 //Enable delivery reports
at+cpms="SM","SM","SR" //Set message storage
at+cnmi=2,1,0,2 //Set message notifications
```

Note the order of the configuration as well. The modem may not let you enable conflicting configurations.

Also note that some modems send the notifications through different channels. In my case connecting E153 in Ubuntu created /dev/ttyUSB0, /dev/ttyUSB1, /dev/ttyUSB2, /dev/ttyUSB3. The notifications for new SMS and delivery reports were only coming through /dev/ttyUSB3 even if I sent SMS using /dev/ttyUSB0.

Comment: Regarding your note gsm modems open up several USB channels for AT Commands, PPP data transfer, GPS, and the like. Only the AT Command channel will support all AT Commands. The other channels only support a subset of the AT Command set. This is dependent on the manufacturer and how they implemented it. Best bet is if there is a manual available for the USB interfaces have a good read through that!

Comment: Many years past but this is the only place where I found the correct information: if you are using E15xx series of Huawei modems, use /dev/ttyUSB2 port for notifications. Others simply don't work. Also, you have to set CNMI to 1,2,0,2

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this init-string in kannel: "ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0" with a huawei e153 and it works in an acceptable manner (I can send sms) so you must use that one or launch `wvdial` and watch stdout to get the right string/command.
Then provide the error message if that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better to use software which can do this? For example [Gammu](http://wammu.eu/gammu) or Gnokii.

And back to the question: Some phones do not like setting all CNMI parameters, check AT+CNMI=? output to see what your phone does support, most likely you need to use something like AT+CNMI=2,,,,0