# How to use minicom to communicate via sms with my usb modem?

Tags: linux, modem

I am using a huawei e355 usb modem on linux. I would like to send my usb modem texts from my cell phone and would want my usb modem to store it in some log file and may be communicate back. How do I go about doing this?

I went through a lot of articles but they were more about setting up the modem rather than using it in this particular way.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786800/huawei-mobile-connect-e170. The answer there may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.question-defense.com/2010/07/27/use-minicom-for-linux-modem-dialup-at-command-testing.

This allows you to send and receive texts from the modem; you can then set a callback for what to do once a text is received. I'm currently working on something along these lines, too, so I don't have a complete answer, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

The best option for your needs would be Gammu. You can download it here http://wammu.eu/. You can also get it over your paket manager.

There is a python API available which makes interacting with texts easier.
For your needs I would recommend you run the gammu-sms daemon (gammu-smsd) and have a script which interacts with the contents of your sms. Check the RunOnReceive variable in the /etc/gammu-smsdrc file.